# How to convert a mortality table to generate a Kaplan-Meier plot

Tags: r, dplyr, datatable, survival-analysis, survival

I have been using the survival package in R to generate Kaplan-Meier plots using tables of mortality data. I am now trying to generate the same type of plots with new data that is in a different format. I would like to convert the data so it is in the same format as the input data I have been using to succesfully make Kaplan-Meier plots.

The data I typically has the following format:

```
ID Entry_type Departure_type Birth_date Death_date  Lifespan
234 B 1 2008-05-01 2020-01-20 10.986995
549 B 1 2014-05-25 2016-02-09 1.711157
235 B 1 2015-02-01 2017-08-01 2.496920ID
```

This data has one individual per row, specified by their ID. The final column is that individual's lifespan

I can generate a Kaplan-Meier plot from this table using the code:

```
survival_plot <- ggsurvplot(
    fit = survfit(Surv(Lifespan, Depart.Type) ~ 1, data = life_span_table), 
    xlab = "Years", 
    ylab = "Overall survival probability",
    surv.median.line = "hv",
    title = "Survival Curve",
    legend.title="")
```

However I now have census record data where I am tracking a cohort born in the year 1905.
The data looks like this:

```
Year Age Total BirthYear CumDeath
1905  0 9262 1905 9262
1906 1 1335 1905 10597
1907 2 514 1905 11111
```

Explainer for the columns:

```
Year: The year being recorded.
Age: The age of the individual from the 1905 cohort in that year.
Total: The number of individuals born in 1905 who died in the recorded year.
BirthYear: Always 1905 for this cohort (redundant information)
CumDeath: The total number of people from the cohort who have died at the point of recording (cumulative death).
```

So this data format does not have an individual per row as previously.
I feel the only way to make identical Kaplan-Meier plots using this data is to reformat it so that there is one individual per row and their Lifespan data is added as a new column to fit the format I usually work with.

Lifespan can be calculated as the difference between the Year and the Birthyear, but I would need to make the number of rows for each lifespan equal to the Total entry for each year. Then I can add a Entry_Type and Departure_Type column for each row that would always be 'B' for Entry_type and '1' for Departure_type.

I usually use dplyr for reformatting tables but I am not sure of the best way to add new rows for each lifespan conditional on the Total entry. Can dplyr do this or am I better off using a loop or lapply function?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should read up on the construction of "life tables". There are several R packages that will do this for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out to be a rather easy exercise using R data.frame row indexing. Consider this toy example (which is pretty similar to yours):

```
tt = data.frame(name=c('a', 'b', 'c'), 
                count=c(1, 2, 3))
# extract counts specifying how many times to replicate each row
counts = tt$count
# construct row indexes
row_positions = seq_along(counts)
# or
row_positions = seq(1, nrow(tt))
# inflate vector of row indexes according to the counts
row_pos_replicated = rep(row_positions, counts)
# use inflated indexes to expand frame rows per `count` values
tt_replicated = tt[row_pos_replicated,]
```

We just expanded rows from `tt` into new frame `tt_replicated` according to the `count` column:

```
> tt_replicated
       name  count
1      a     1
2      b     2
2.1    b     2
3      c     3
3.1    c     3
3.2    c     3
```

Solution for your frame based on above and using more condensed syntax:

```
census_data = read.csv(text = "Year Age Total BirthYear CumDeath
1905 0 9262 1905 9262
1906 1 1335 1905 10597
1907 2 514 1905 11111", sep="")

census_data_for_KMplot = census_data[rep(seq(1,
                                             nrow(census_data)),
                                         census_data$CumDeath),]
```

Let's count number of rows for each `Year` (using `data.table`):

```
> data.table::setDT(census_data_for_KMplot)[, .N, by=Year]
   Year     N
1: 1905  9262
2: 1906 10597
3: 1907 11111
```

Using `data.table` for speed and somewhat simpler syntax (notice no `sep=` in `fread` and no `,` inside `[]` while row indexing):

```
library(data.table)

census_data = fread(text = "Year Age Total BirthYear CumDeath
1905 0 9262 1905 9262
1906 1 1335 1905 10597
1907 2 514 1905 11111")

census_data_for_KMplot = census_data[rep(seq_along(census_data$CumDeath), 
                                     census_data$CumDeath)]
census_data_for_KMplot[, .N, by=Year]

   Year     N
1: 1905  9262
2: 1906 10597
3: 1907 11111
```

Comment: Thanks I think this is very close but I miscommunicated, I should have said it is dependent on Total not CumDeath. For the year 1907 there should only be 514 rows/entries because 514 individuals born in 1905 died in that year. With your code the N increases every year but what I need is the number of rows for each year to correspond to the value in the 'Total' column. I will try to modify the code as it was my error.